# Checkbox filter by type - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, sorting, filter

Have anyone ideas how I can filter data by "type" checking a custom "checkbox"?

I have response from API like this

```
"notifications": [
        {
            "id": 255,
            "type": 23,
            "date": "2020-06-26 11:14:23",
            "message": "Add %s something %s.",
            "placeholder": {
                "group_post": {
                    "id": 16,
                    "name": "Berlin",
                    "avatar": "source",
                    "post_id": 172,
                    "post_text": "asdasd..."
                },
                "group": {
                    "id": 16,
                    "name": "Bowling",
                    "avatar": "source",
                    "post_id": 172,
                    "post_text": "asdasd..."
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 246,
            "type": 20,
            "date": "2020-06-10 11:05:55",
            "message": "You have rejected %s invitation to %s.",
            "placeholder": {
                "user": {
                    "id": 1283661,
                    "frozen": false,
                    "avatar": "source",
                    "private_data": false,
                    "login": "gut",
                    "online": 1
                },
                "group": {
                    "id": 24,
                    "name": "tomas",
                    "avatar": "source"
                }
            }
        }
     }
  ]
```

I have lists full of notifications but in case where user choose category I want to filter data and show only this values which user checked.

@Edit

Here is a custom "Checkbox"

```
<DropMenu
            activator={({ isOpen, toggle, triggerRef, selectedItems }) => {
                return (
                    <button type="button" ref={triggerRef} onClick={toggle}>
                        {selectedItems && selectedItems.length ? (
                            <Btn color="white">{selectedItems.map(val => `${val.content}, `)}</Btn>
                        ) : (
                            <Btn color="white">None</Btn>
                        )}
                    </button>
                );
            }}
            items={[
                {
                    content: "value1",
                    value: 1,
                },
                {
                    content: "value2",
                    value: 2,
                },
                {
                    content: "value3",
                    value: 3,
                },
                {
                    content: "value4",
                    value: 4,
                },
                {
                    content: "value5",
                    value: 5,
                },
                {
                    content: "value6",
                    value: 6,
                },
                {
                    content: "value7",
                    value: 7,
                },
            ]}
            selected={select2}
            onSelect={value => check2(value)}
        />
```

select2 is in hook's state and I want compare value from checkbox with types which api includes.
For example "value" 7 is equal "type" 23.

Comment: share what you have tried so far

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow, please share your attemp to solve your problem first